# Balance events on a hosted wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

If one wants to create a trading wallet for ETH what Ethereum JSON-RPC events one needs to listen for incoming balance updates? Idea would be to reflect Ethereum account state in a local database.

Or is there another way to do this... read Ethereum wallet database direcly?

I am using Python as the server-side programming language. I guess purely cliet-side trustles JavaScript wallet might work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a simple way to filter for only balance-modifying transactions in a given account.

However, with the web3 JS library, it is possible to query for a specific address's balance using the [getBalance](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance) method. Example usage:

```
var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(address);
console.log(address, "has", web3.fromWei(balance, "ether")).toString(), "ETH!");
```

Depending on your needs, you may be able to simply call getBalance when you need it. If you want it to automatically update, or if you don't want the sychronous call, you could use the [filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter) method. Example usage:

```
var balance;
web3.eth.filter("latest", function(error, result) {
   if (!error) {
       balance = web3.eth.getBalance(address);
   }
});
```

web3 must attach to an Ethereum node, so this may not work in a client-side environment. On the bright side, all of these are based on the standard [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) API, so you may be able to work out something pythonic server-side.

Comment: Thanks. This is a step to a right direction. Is it possible to know what transactions in `filter` cause balance updates or how to decode those transactions? E.g filtering the transactions provided by filter :)

Comment: filter("pending") or filter("latest") just call the callback if there is a new transaction/block respectively.  Unfortunately, there's no (easy) way to know exactly what a transaction did, because a subtransaction (contract called by a contract) might have sent funds. However, if you are using a wallet contract, you can write the contract's code to sent an event when a transaction is received/sent. This may be closer to what you need.

Comment: I spotted a similar question on Ethereum Commmunity forums: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/4324/how-cant-i-get-invoked-transactions-use-web3-js-api - apparently it's possible because etherchain is doing it :)

Comment: Also for substransactions: would they generate separate events or not? I'd assume not the whole transaction chain is processed in one transaction written to a block, so one should check the balances of all involved addresses at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Looks like it is being extensively discussed here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1897

Comment: I would suspect etherchain is actually running a specific kind of full node that allows EVM-level inspection. [Events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events) are a solidity feature that allow web3 to know if a specific section of code is run. Usually I don't end up carrying in what circumstance an event was logged, only that it was logged.